# No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.RatingBar.Small'

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I want to use a custom ratingbar. I did all the steps said here: http://android-helper.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-custom-ratingbar-example.html

The only problem is this:

```
No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Widget.RatingBar.Small'.
```

I've searched and some says that google restric it and do not allow to access this file anymore. I've tried to copy the style from android sdk but it's not a single file, it refers to some other drawable, I need to include them too.

Is there anyway to solve this problem? How can I use this widget? I need it to be small.

thanks

Comment: @android:style/Widget.RatingBar.Small use it instead of @style/Widget.RatingBar.Small and as per your example code you need custom drawable images of Rating bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create custom style for **custom rating bar**. You can try with this in your style.

```
  <resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />
<style name="foodRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/star_rating_bar_full</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">48dip</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

and your xml layout will be like this.

```
      <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/ratingbar_default"
            style="@style/foodRatingBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:numStars="5" />
```

in your code, use setOnratingbarchangelistener

```
        ratingBar_default
            .setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new  RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar,
                        float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    ratingValue = String.valueOf(rating);
                    System.out.println(ratingValue);

                }
            });
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I've tried this , the problem is rating bar icons are very big , I need the to be small . any way ?

Comment: make the images suiltable to the minHeight and maxHeight in style

Comment: How loopy is it that the images have to match the layout size? Scale the damn images to fit the layout size! God damn it Android!!

Answer (score 2):

you can use this instead..

```
@style/Widget.Holo.RatingBar.Small
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Instead

```
style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
```